# Get elements by name not working when targeting inside ID .getElementsbyTagName is not a function error

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble targeting an input with a 'name' attribute inside a form with and ID using vanilla JS. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <input name="hello" value="hello">
        <input name="suburb" value="suburb">
    </form>
```

JS:

```
   var form = document.getElementById('form').getElementsByName('hello')[0].value;
    console.log(form);
```

I'm getting an error in firebug - '.getElementsbyName is not a function'

I tried using tag name instead which worked, but I would prefer to target based on the name attribute so it's more specific in case other input fields are added dynamically.

Thanks.

Comment: getElementsByName() is a method of the document object .... I don't think you can chain it the way you have in your code

Comment: In your JavaScript you write `getElementsByName` but you get error message for `getElementsByTagName`? Is there a typo somewhere or is this the problem you are facing?

Comment: Yes that was a typo, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do

```
var foo = document.forms['myForm']['hello'];
```

you can also use dot notation for easier coding. getting suburb's value:

```
var input = document.forms.myForm.suburb,
    suburbValue = input.value;
```

but as @sundeep suggests in the comments, `.getElementsByName()` cannot be chained to a `document.getElementById('form')`

Comment: This is a perfect solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

getElementByName is a function of document object. So use it directly with document.

```
var form = document.getElementsByName('hello')[0].value;
```

[CheckHere](https://jsfiddle.net/bfjzsztz/)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately there's 4 forms with the same name attributes in the site I'm using this for. I only want to change the values on one form.

Comment: @dust when you get element by name you receive an array of all elements with same name if you want to select the first just use array notation [0] as given in above example.